# SQL query to find number of questions asked on a specific day

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select Date(createdOn) Date, count(createdOn) "No of Questions" 
from Questions 
group by Date(createdOn);
```

Date                  No of Questions

2015-08-25                  3

2015-08-26                 8

2015-06-27                 13

2015-06-28                 35

I am not an expert in mysql. Based on my requirement I want the number of questions asked on a specific day. When I execute above query I get results like above.

**How do I get the result for only current date i.e. 2015-06-28?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Group By` use `where` condition like this:

```
select Date(createdOn) `Dated`, count(createdOn) "No of Questions" 
from Questions 
where Date(createdOn) = CURDATE();
```

Do check if you have data specific to the CURDATE() ie, 2015-08-28 eles try like this:

```
select Date(createdOn) `Dated`, count(createdOn) "No of Questions" 
from Questions 
where Date(createdOn) = '2015-08-26';
```

Comment: It is giving  error like ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Date(createdOn) Date, count(createdOn) "No of Questions" from Questions where Da' at line 1

Comment: @BhupatiPatel:- Updated my answer. Check now!

Comment: Sorry I am getting NULL 0.

Comment: @BhupatiPatel:- Do you have data in your table for the current date ie, 2015-08-28?

Comment: Thanks @Rahul, verified again. I am getting the correct result now.

Comment: Earlier I had no data for CURDATE() i.e. 2015-08-28. Before building the question I had data till 2015-08-27 . Thats why I was getting NULL 0 . Thanks.

Comment: @BhupatiPatel:- Welcome. Also to inform you that CURDATE() will always return you todays date, so if you are not sure about it then you can specify the data for which you want the data for :)

Comment: @BhupatiPatel:- Check this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @BhupatiPatel:- Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 select Date(createdOn) Date, count(createdOn) "No of Questions" 
    from Questions 
    group by Date(createdOn)
    having Date(createdOn) = CURDATE();
```

Comment: Why to use Group By and then HAVING when a simple Where can solve the purpose? ;)

Comment: I had tried this earlier It gives error like ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'createdOn' in 'having clause'

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
        WHERE CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) = CONVERT(DATE, @YourDate)

Comment: btw YourDate would be sth Like 
DECLARE @YourDate DATE = new Date('20150827')